# Problem with INSERT INTO SQL Server database using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I am trying to insert data into my SQL Server database in C#.

I am fairly new at programming, and would like to learn the correct way of doing so.

So far, I have a database class :

```
public SqlConnection connection()
{
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder.DataSource = "DESKTOP-UPVVOJP";
    builder.InitialCatalog = "Lagersystem";
    builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;

    return new SqlConnection(builder.ToString());
}
```

Product class file :

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int ProductStock { get; set; }
    public int ProductCategoryID { get; set; }
    public int ProductEmployeeID { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProductCreatedDate { get; set; }

    // Constructor
    public Product(string productname, int productstock, int productcategoryid, int productemployeeid)
    {
        ProductName = productname;
        ProductStock = productstock;
        ProductCategoryID = productcategoryid;
        ProductEmployeeID = productemployeeid;
        ProductCreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Insert method in my program :

```
static void InsertProduct(string productname, int productstock, int productcategoryid, int productemployeeid)
{
    Database db = new Database();

    SqlConnection conn = db.connection();

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Products (ProductName, ProductStock, ProductCategoryID, ProductEmployeeID, ProductCreatedDate)
                                                 VALUES('{0}', {1}, {2}, {3}, '{4}')", conn))
    {
        string formattet = string.Format(productname, productstock, productcategoryid, productemployeeid, DateTime.Now);
        Console.WriteLine(formattet);

        conn.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

and my main method :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Indtast Produktnavn :");
        string productname = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Hvor mange er der på lager? : ");
        int productstock = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Hvilken kategori ID hører produktet til? : ");
        int productcategoryid = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Hvilket medarbejder ID har oprettet produktet? : ");
        int productemployeeid = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        try
        {
            InsertProduct(productname, productstock, productcategoryid, productemployeeid);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

My database has the following setup :

```
CREATE TABLE Products 
(
    ProductID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ProductName nvarchar(32) NOT NULL,
    ProductStock INT,
    ProductCategoryID INT,
    ProductEmployeeID int NOT NULL,
    ProductCreatedDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
);
```

By running this, I can enter the data "productname, stock, categoryid, employeeid"

As "Jacket, 10, 1, 2" this should work as i have a category with the id 1. and a employee with the id 2.

When I run the program, I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near '1'

My guess falls hard on some error in this area :

```
VALUES('{0}', {1}, {2}, {3}, '{4}')"
```

Comment: Start by forgetting you ever saw anyone use String.Format() to insert values directly into SQL queries, because that's called "SQL Injection" and is not the right way to do things - it leads to issues like [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/). Instead you want to use [SqlCommand.Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters) so that values can be inserted using their correct data types and you don't have to worry about escaping crazy things like apostrophes in strings like `Jack O'Neill`.

Comment: In your previous question your code uses parameters correctly. Why did you change your technique here? And please start marking the appropriate response as the answer rather copy/pasting the code provided as your own "answer". Give a little credit for the free code others provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using query parameters, like so:

```
conn.Open();

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
    @"INSERT INTO Products
        (ProductName, ProductStock, ProductCategoryID, ProductEmployeeID, ProductCreatedDate)
        VALUES(@ProductName, @ProductStock, @ProductCategoryID, @ProductEmployeeID, getDate())", 
    conn
);
command.Parameters.Add("@ProductName", productname);
command.Parameters.Add("@ProductStock", productstock);
command.Parameters.Add("@ProductCategoryID", productcategoryid);
command.Parameters.Add("@ProductEmployeeID", productemployeeid);

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Note that you can compute the current date/time directly in the query, using SQL Server function `getDate()` rather than pass it from c#.

Comment: And additionally, I'd recommend not using these deprecated overloads of `.Add` - use the one where you explicitly specify the **data type** of the parameter, instead: `command.Parameters.Add("@ProductName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 32).Value = productname;`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, by using this correct way, its working flawless. you rock!

```
        static void InsertProduct(string productname, int productstock, int productcategoryid, int productemployeeid)
        {
            Database db = new Database();
            SqlConnection conn = db.connection();
            conn.Open();
            using SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Products
                (ProductName, ProductStock, ProductCategoryID, ProductEmployeeID, ProductCreatedDate)
                VALUES(@ProductName, @ProductStock, @ProductCategoryID, @ProductEmployeeID, getDate())",conn);
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProductName", productname));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProductStock", productstock));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProductCategoryID", productcategoryid));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProductEmployeeID", productemployeeid));

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```